# How to deploy Python Google App Engine managed VMS from Windows?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, boot2docker

I have an issue deploying Python application into App Engine managed VMS from Windows. I'm using local docker builds and this phase seems to work correctly.
Then the upload phase starts and it ends with the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\googlecloudsdk\gcloud\gcloud.py", line 228, in main
    _cli.Execute()
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\cli.py", line 580, in Execute
    result = args.cmd_func(cli=self, args=args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\backend.py", line 1129, in Run
    result = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\googlecloudsdk\appengine\app_commands\deploy.py", line 215, in Run
    implicit_remote_build)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\googlecloudsdk\appengine\lib\deploy_command_util.py", line 135, in BuildAndPushDockerImages
    docker_client)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\googlecloudsdk\appengine\lib\images\push.py", line 56, in BuildAndPushDockerImage
    r.Push(image)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\googlecloudsdk\appengine\lib\images\registry.py", line 116, in Push
    _Retry(ProgressHandler, 'push', InnerPush)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\googlecloudsdk\appengine\lib\images\registry.py", line 49, in _Retry
    raise e
APIError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error ("v1 ping attempt failed witherror: Get https://appengine.gcr.io/v1/_ping: dial tcp: i/o timeout. If this private registry supports only HTTP or HTTPS with an unknown CA certificate, please add `--insecure-registry appengine.gcr.io` to the daemon's arguments. In the case of HTTPS, if you have access to the registry's CA certificate, no need for the flag; simply place the CA certificate at /etc/docker/certs.d/appengine.gcr.io/ca.crt")

If you would like to report this issue, please run the following command:
  gcloud feedback
```

Has anybody encountered similar issue?

I'm using Google Cloud SDK 0.9.76 and boot2docker 1.5.0

Comment: Does your private registry support only HTTP or HTTPS with an unknown CA certificate?

Comment: This is really Google's private repository. They seem to use Google Internet Authority G2 as CA. I have no idea if it's known

Comment: Ah ok. In that case there might not be anything you can do atm. I'd suggest to simply try it again soon.